# How to get all data from API using objects with Newtonsoft.Json and I receive wrong data in xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I try to get data from API in xamarin but I receive only the first data in array.

This is the [API](http://194.141.118.43:3000/?id=16) and this is the screenshot from the code:

[image: Why in waterData I receive only the first values ?]

Why in waterData I receive only the first values and also the date and AlertLevelForecast is not correct ?

My objects look like:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast
{
    public class WaterDataJson
    {
        [JsonProperty("ardaforecast")]
        public List[] ArdaForecast { get; set; }

        
        [JsonProperty("Dt")]
        public DateTime DateTimeForecast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AL")]
        public int AlertLevelForecast { get; set; }
        
    }

    
    public class List
    {
        [JsonProperty("Dt")]
        public string DateTimeForecast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AL")]
        public int AlertLevelForecast { get; set; }
    }
    

}
```

My RestService class look like:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast
{
    public class RestService
    {
        HttpClient _client;

        public RestService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task<WaterDataJson> GetWaterData(string query)
        {
            WaterDataJson waterData = new WaterDataJson();

            try
            {
                var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    waterData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaterDataJson>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            return waterData;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I receive only one wrong `AlertLevelForecast` and wrong `DateTimeForecast` ?

**What should I do in the object class to get all the data with the correct dates and values?**

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: Your model doesn't match the data being returned by the API. ardaforecast is an array containing another ayray and an object. If you wrote the API, you might want to change that, if not, change your model.

Comment: Can you give me example what to change in the model to return correct data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed to deserialize it  and found that the only way  that you can do it using newtonsoft json is to create this classes (this solution was tested using Visual Studio and Postman)

```
    public class WaterDataJson
    {
        public List<ForecastBody> Ardaforecast { get; set; }
    }
    public class ForecastBody
    {
        public ForecastItem[] Items { get; set; }
        public ForecastDetails Details { get; set; }
    }

   public class ForecastDetails
    {
        public int fieldCount { get; set; }
        public int affectedRows { get; set; }
        public int insertId { get; set; }
        public int serverStatus { get; set; }
        public int warningCount { get; set; }
        public int changedRows { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool protocol41 { get; set; }
    }
    public class ForecastItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("Dt")]
        public DateTime DateTimeForecast { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AL")]
        public int AlertLevelForecast { get; set; }
    }
```

the json will be like this

```
{"ardaforecast":[ { "items": [{"Dt":"2021-07-22T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-27T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-27T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1}],"details":{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":34,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}}]}
```

If you have the control the easiest way is to change API, if you dont, you can change json output using String.Replace

```
 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   
var json = content.Replace("\"ardaforecast\":[[", "\"ardaforecast\":[ {\"items\": [")
                               .Replace("}],{\"fieldCount\"", "}],\"details\":{\"fieldCount\"")
                               .Replace("}]}", "}}]}");
 waterData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaterDataJson>(json);
```

Comment: @PizhevRacing I am sorry but it doesn' t have any weatherData  property at all. Where did you find it?  Have you fixed your classes?

Comment: @PizhevRacing I put more details in my answer. Pls try it again;